# Looping through columns that generates multiple columns automatically

Tags: python, pandas

**Table:**

- Need to ignore timestamp.
- n2-n1, n3- n2 ..... rows are not present in my case.
- Need a fast solution, since the dataset is somewhat large.

|  | time | n1 | n2 | n3 | n5 | n6 | n7 | n8 | n9 | n10 | n11 | `n2 - n1` | `n3 - n2` | `n4 - n3` | ... | `n11-n10` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 12:50 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 13:50 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Use this code to fiddle:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = ['11:50', '12:50', '13:50']
data_1 = {'time': time,
          'n1': [1, 5, 8],
          'n2': [2, 6 ,7],
          'n3': [3, 7 ,6],
          'n5': [4, 8, 5],
          'n6': [4, 8, 5],
          'n7': [4, 8, 5],
          'n8': [4, 8, 5],
          'n9': [4, 8, 5],
          'n10': [4, 8, 5],
          'n11': [4, 8, 5],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data_1)
df1
```

I need to generate `n2-n1`, `n3-n2`...`n11-n10` columns. With all differences respectively. How can I generate these columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with `zip()`:

```py
for fst, snd in zip(df1.columns[1:], df1.columns[2:]):
    df1[f"{snd}-{fst}"] = df1[snd] - df1[fst]

print(df1)
```

This outputs:

```py
    time  n1  n2  n3  n5  n6  n7  n8  n9  n10  n11  n2-n1  n3-n2  n5-n3  n6-n5  n7-n6  n8-n7  n9-n8  n10-n9  n11-n10
0  11:50   1   2   3   4   4   4   4   4    4    4      1      1      1      0      0      0      0       0        0
1  12:50   5   6   7   8   8   8   8   8    8    8      1      1      1      0      0      0      0       0        0
2  13:50   8   7   6   5   5   5   5   5    5    5     -1     -1     -1      0      0      0      0       0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) method over the columns (`axis=1`) to compute consecutive column differences

```
df1 = df1.join(
    df1.filter(like='n')  # get only the columns that start with 'n'
       .diff(axis=1) # consecutive column differences 
       .dropna(axis=1)  # drop the first column: n1 - nothing = NaN
       .rename(columns=lambda col: f'{col}-n{int(col[1:]) - 1}') # relabel the columns
)
```

Output:

|  | time | n1 | n2 | n3 | n5 | n6 | n7 | n8 | n9 | n10 | n11 | n2-n1 | n3-n2 | n5-n4 | n6-n5 | n7-n6 | n8-n7 | n9-n8 | n10-n9 | n11-n10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11:50 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 12:50 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 13:50 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | -1 | -1 | -1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |